# How can I turn on the macOS firewall from a script

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, firewall

I'm setting up a new Mac Mini and I am using a script assembled from commands that I've accumulated over the years to set `defaults`, create directory structures, install software, and otherwise customize my Macs the way I want them.  The first command--to turn on the firewall--is failing to do anything.  How is the firewall currently turned on, in Catalina?

The command I'm using is

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -integer 1
```

This is the same thing I'm finding by Googling (or an alternate form with `-int` instead of `-integer`).

If it has not changed, what could be preventing it from working?

Answer (score 2):

macOS now uses the [`pf`](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html) firewall (from OpenBSD).  Since Mac OS X Lion (10.7) circa 2012, the firewall [`ipfw`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipfirewall) was deprecated in favor of `pf`

The command to disable the `pf` firewall is:

```
% sudo pfctl -d
```

For full command line options for `pfctl` see [`man pfctl`](http://man.openbsd.org/pfctl).

Comment: it is _possible_ that this accomplishes exactly what I want, but the change is not reflected in the System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Firewall control panel.  Is that simply a bug on Apple's part? or is the setting there different from what can be done with `pfctl`?

Comment: This firewall is way to complex to show in the GUI.  What you see in the Firewall control panel is just the basics.

Comment: yes, but is there a reason that the GUI wouldn't reflect changes made in the shell?  Is this simply an oversight on Apple's part?

Comment: Possibly. I’ll have to investigate.  I typically don’t use the software firewalls built into operating systems.  I either don’t turn on the service (it can’t be exploited if it’s not there) and/or I put a hardware based firewall between me and everything else.  I do know that the GUI that Apple puts is for the non-technical user that wouldn’t be comfortable writing `pf` rules and those can get super complex.